# Some advice and guidance on rolling your own scikit-learn estimator?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to create my own little neural network estimator. I'm trying to follow the conventions mentioned [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/), but I have some questions.

Suppose my class is something like

For now, I would like the user to specify `num_layers` and `n_epochs`.

```
class NN(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, num_layers=[10, 5], n_epochs=10):
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.n_epochs = n_epochs
```

Am I understanding correctly that I should *not* be setting up the network architecture in `__init__()`? I have quite a bit of code that does this, is it really all supposed to go in `fit()`? I think the natural place for this code would be in `__init__()`...

I would also like some clarity on the underscoring at the end of variable names. I think that, for example, the weights in each layer should be underscored, but what about extra helper variables that aren't really estimating anything? Does scikit actually care about the underscores, or is this purely a convention for readability?

Also, how are scores computed if I do not provide a `score()` function but I do provide a `predict()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should ask such specific questions on [scikit-learn](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/scikit-learn-general) mailing list, but i'll try to help:

1) You can read comments in BaseEstimator class (base.py):

```
Base class for all estimators in scikit-learn

Notes
-----
All estimators should specify all the parameters that can be set
at the class level in their ``__init__`` as explicit keyword
arguments (no ``*args`` or ``**kwargs``).
```

I can also add that GridSearch/BaseSearch works in such a way, that it sets parameters with set_params directly on initialized model, and then calls fit() on every estimator. That's why you should move every dependent (from constructor parameters) variable initialization from  `__init__`   to `fit`. All fields which you initialize from `__init__` parameters should be named exactly as that parameter, otherwise `get_params` method of `BaseEstimator` will return None instead of correct value of a field:

```
from sklearn import base

class Foo(base.BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, parameter_a, parameter_b, parameter_c):
        # Correct naming of internal fields
        self.parameter_a = parameter_a
        self.parameter_b = parameter_b
        # Incorrect naming of internal fields
        self.parameter_c_incorrect = parameter_c
p = Foo(1, 2, 3)
print(p.get_params())
# prints {'parameter_c': None, 'parameter_a': 1, 'parameter_b': 2}
```

Im this case clone will also return wrong results.
[Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343024/override-method-for-a-collection-of-classes-implementing-an-interface/32347230#32347230)

2) I think it's purely conventional, you may read [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

3) `ClassifierMixin`, `RegressorMixin`, etc
   These mixins are sort of classes, which you can add to your class for additional functionality, but by themselves they cannot do anything (You cannot instantiate them). Look at their implementation in base.py.